# Adding second external github project to visual studios solution

Tags: git, visual-studio, github

We have an internal Git repository that is hosted on Team Foundation Server.  I found a github repository I want to add to my solution and do development on it and to be able keep track of changes outside of our main repository.

How would I add the external github repository to my visual studio's solution so that I can track changes on that repo separately from my main repository?

If I make a change to the external github repo, it wouldn't push those changes to our main repo, and I could then send pull requests up to github with feature enhancements.

Answer (score 0):

You could introduce the github repo as a submodule:

```
git submodule add <github repository> <path inside your TFS repo>
```

But be aware that removing the submodule later on from your repo is hard and would imply history rewrting.

For more options of git submodule see https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule

You will be able to push to the github repo as usual while you are in one of the github repos subdirectories.

If the github repo changes, you will have a commit of the submodule hash in your TFS repo. This is necessary as your repo rely on the commit of the github repo. Any commit to github could otherwise break Building your TFS repo.